# asyncIO multithreaded server with two coroutines

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, python-asyncio

I'm programming a server in Python3, which takes screenshot and sends it over websockets. I have coroutine for handling connection and I would like to create another coroutine for taking screenshot at some interval. Screenshot coroutine will probably run in different thread and I will need to propagate the result to some shared variable with read-write lock, to be able to send it. My questions: (result should be multiplatform, if possible)

1. How is it possible to schedule tasks like this? I created server which runs forever, and I can create periodical coroutine, but somehow I can't put them together in one loop.
2. What is a good way to propagate the result from one thread (or coroutine, if server is single threaded) to another?

I found this piece of code similar to this and I can't get it to work (second coroutine doesn't execute). Can someone correct this with and without multithreading?

```
async def print_var():
    global number
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    print(number)


async def inc_var():
    global number
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    number += 1

number = 0

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(print_var())
asyncio.async(inc_var)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

**Post-answer edit**

In the end after more hours of googling, I actually got it to work on a single thread, so there's no danger of race condition. (But I'm still not sure what ensure_future does, and why it isn't called on event loop.)

```
users = set()

def register(websocket):
    users.add(websocket)

def unregister(websocket):
    users.remove(websocket)

async def get_screenshot():
    global screenshot
    while True:
        screenshot = screenshot()
        await asyncio.sleep(0.2)

async def server(websocket, path):
    global screenshot
    register(websocket)
    try:
        async for message in websocket:
            respond(screenshot)
    finally:
        unregister(websocket)

def main():
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(
        websockets.serve(server, 'localhost', 6789))
    asyncio.ensure_future(get_screenshot())
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()

main()
```

Comment: `asyncio.ensure_future()` converts the given object into a future, or raises an exception. When given a coroutine object (the object you get when you invoke a coroutine like `get_screenshot`), it creates and returns a `Task`, a subclass of `Future`. You can think of the returned task as running in the "background". `ensure_future` can work without being passed an event loop because it calls `asyncio.get_event_loop()` to obtain the default one. If you are dealing with a coroutine, you [should](https://github.com/python/asyncio/issues/477#issuecomment-268709555) call `loop.create_task` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python 3.7:

```
import asyncio

import websockets

CAPTURE_INTERVAL = 1
running = True
queues = set()


async def handle(ws, path):
    queue = asyncio.Queue()
    queues.add(queue)
    while running:
        data = await queue.get()
        if not data:
            break
        await ws.send(data)


def capture_screen():
    # Do some work here, preferably in C extension without holding the GIL
    return b'screenshot data'


async def main():
    global running
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    server = await websockets.serve(handle, 'localhost', 8765)
    try:
        while running:
            data = await loop.run_in_executor(None, capture_screen)
            for queue in queues:
                queue.put_nowait(data)
            await asyncio.sleep(CAPTURE_INTERVAL)
    finally:
        running = False
        for queue in queues:
            queue.put_nowait(None)
        server.close()
        await server.wait_closed()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Please note, this is only for demonstrating the producer-consumer fan-out pattern. The `queues` are not essential - you can simply send `data` to all `server.sockets` in `main()` directly, while in `handle()` you should worry about incoming websocket messages. For example, client may control image compression rate like this:

```
import asyncio

import websockets

CAPTURE_INTERVAL = 1
DEFAULT = b'default'
qualities = {}


async def handle(ws, path):
    try:
        async for req in ws:
            qualities[ws] = req
    finally:
        qualities.pop(ws, None)


def capture_screen():
    # Do some work here, preferably in C extension without holding the GIL
    return {
        DEFAULT: b'default screenshot data',
        b'60': b'data at 60% quality',
        b'80': b'data at 80% quality',
    }


async def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    server = await websockets.serve(handle, 'localhost', 8765)
    try:
        while True:
            data = await loop.run_in_executor(None, capture_screen)
            for ws in server.sockets:
                quality = qualities.get(ws, DEFAULT)
                if quality not in data:
                    quality = DEFAULT
                asyncio.create_task(ws.send(data[quality]))
            await asyncio.sleep(CAPTURE_INTERVAL)
    finally:
        server.close()
        await server.wait_closed()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: The server actually only sends screenshot when polled (should've mentioned), so there's no need for a queue, only shared variable with a read write lock, but that could be implemented using your example. Thanks